# Flutter: How to change Radius of the cursor in the TextField?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to change radius of the cursor in the TextField. In Flutter is there any way to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In TextField there is a property called `cursorRadius`. You can use it set the desired cursorRadius.

Here is the code for it.

```dart
TextField (
     cursorRadius: Radius.circular(5.0), //you can play with the number to get the result you want
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
        labelText: 'Username',
      ),
    ),
```

**Default Results**

[image]

**Results after using the `cursorRadius` property**

[image]